# Rust import PAM C functions

Tags: rust, pam

I'm trying to figure out how to write a Linux PAM in Rust and I've started with [this repo](https://github.com/rcatolino/pam_sm_rust). When I compile it with `--features libpam` (which enables `#[link(name="pam")]` that imports external C functions), the compiler complains:

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
...
note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpam: No such file or directory
```

Looking around SO, I've realized that the `pam` library was not found to be linked. However, I just cannot figure out how to either install it (I can find many `libpam-something` packages, but no `libpam`) or locate it such that I can indicate to the compiler/linker where to find it.

When I look into other crates that also work with PAM, they all import the C functions using `#[link(name="pam")]`, and none specifies how to make it work.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: You can `apt install libpam-modules`, AFAIC, to install most popular pam modules.

Comment: I already have that package installed. Anyway, I suppose that the `pam` library I'm looking for would 'contain' files like `security/pam_headers.h` etc., not a concrete implementation.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libpam0g-dev should fit probably

Comment: Wow, that was it! Thanks! You could post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The necessary headers for PAM library can be installed on Ubuntu as part of `libpam0g-dev` package (link for [jammy](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libpam0g-dev)):

```bash
sudo apt install libpam0g-dev
```

Debian package has the same name (so `sudo apt-get install libpam0g-dev`), CentOS uses `pam-devel` package for that (`sudo yum install pam-devel`).

Alternatively, on any platform you can use the source code [from github](https://github.com/Distrotech/Linux-PAM) and follow the installation instructions from README.